# Task solution for best performance

Tags: python, mysql, sql

What's the best / fastest solution for the following task:

Used technology: MySQL database + Python

I'm downloading a `data.sql` file. It's format:

```sql
INSERT INTO `temp_table` VALUES (group_id,city_id,zip_code,post_code,earnings,'group_name',votes,'city_name',person_id,'person_name',networth);
INSERT INTO `temp_table` VALUES (group_id,city_id,zip_code,post_code,earnings,'group_name',votes,'city_name',person_id,'person_name',networth);
.
.
```

Values in each row differ.

Tables structures: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8f10d6

A person can have multiple cities

A person can be only in one group or can be without group.

A group can have multiple persons

And i know from which country these .sql data are.

I need to split these data into 3 tables. And I will be updating data that are already in the tables and if not then I will create new row. 
So I came up with 2 solutions:

1. Split the values from the file via python and then perform for each line 3x select + 3x update/insert in the transaction.
2. Somehow bulk insert the data into a temporary table and then manipulate with the data inside a database - meaning for each row in the temporary table I will perform 3 select queries (one to each actual table) and if I find row I will send 3x (update query and if not then I run insert query).

I will be running this function multiple times per day with over 10K lines in the .sql file and it will be updating / creating over 30K rows in the database.

**//EDIT**

My inserting / updating code now:

```py
autocomit = "SET autocommit=0"
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(autocomit)
data = data.sql
lines = data.splitlines
for line in lines:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor: 
        cursor.execute(line)

temp_data = "SELECT * FROM temp_table"
with connection.cursor() as cursor: 
    cursor.execute(temp_data)
    temp_data = cursor.fetchall()

for temp_row in temp_data:
    group_id = temp_row[0]
    city_id = temp_row[1]
    zip_code = temp_row[2]
    post_code = temp_row[3]
    earnings = temp_row[4]
    group_name = temp_row[5]
    votes = temp_row[6]
    city_name = temp_row[7]
    person_id = temp_row[8]
    person_name = temp_row[9]
    networth = temp_row[10]

group_select = "SELECT * FROM perm_group WHERE group_id = %s AND countryid_fk = %s"
group_values = (group_id, countryid)
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        row = cursor.execute(group_select, group_values)
    if row == 0 and group_id != 0: #If person doesn't have group do not create
       group_insert = "INSERT INTO perm_group (group_id, group_name, countryid_fk) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
       group_insert_values = (group_id, group_name, countryid)
       with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(group_insert, group_insert_values) 
            groupid = cursor.lastrowid
    elif row == 1 and group_id != 0: 
        group_update = "UPDATE perm_group SET group_name = group_name WHERE group_id = %s and countryid_fk = %s"
        group_update_values = (group_id, countryid)
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(group_update, group_update_values)

        #Select group id for current row to assign correct group to the person    
        group_certain_select = "SELECT id FROM perm_group WHERE group_id = %s and countryid_fk = %s"
        group_certain_select_values = (group_id, countryid)
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(group_certain_select, group_certain_select_values)
            groupid = cursor.fetchone()
#.
#.
#.
#Repeating the same piece of code for person and city
```

Measured time: 206 seconds - which is not acceptable.

```py
       group_insert = "INSERT INTO perm_group (group_id, group_name, countryid_fk) VALUES (%s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE group_id = %s, group_name = %s"
       group_insert_values = (group_id, group_name, countryid, group_id, group_name)
       with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(group_insert, group_insert_values) 

        #Select group id for current row to assign correct group to the person    
        group_certain_select = "SELECT id FROM perm_group WHERE group_id = %s and countryid_fk = %s"
        group_certain_select_values = (group_id, countryid)
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute(group_certain_select, group_certain_select_values)
            groupid = cursor.fetchone()
```

Measured time: from 30 to 50 seconds. (Still quite long, but it's getting better)

Are there any other better (faster) options on how to do it?

Thanks in advice, popcorn

Comment: Can you provide more context? Have you done any benchmarks? What are the other tables like? See: [mcve].

Comment: Write a trigger in table after insert that insert the data automatiocally for every row into the other two.

Comment: @AlexanderCécile I added table example and one measured time from what I've been using.

Comment: This level of abstraction makes it almost impossible to construct a useful answer

Comment: @Strawberry Tell me what should I add and I will. ;) But Gordons answer seems satisfying enough for me. I will test it in 10 hours.

Comment: @popcorn are you still looking for answers/information on this?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile Yes, see updated question. I added another method i tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you load the data into a staging table and do the processing in SQL.

Basically, your ultimate result is a set of SQL tables, so SQL is necessarily going to be part of the solution.  You might as well put as much logic into the database as you can, to simply the number of tools needed.

Loading 10,000 rows should not take much time.  However, if you have a choice of data formats, I would recommend a CSV file over `insert`s.  `insert`s incur extra overhead, if only because they are larger.

Once the data is in the database, I would not worry much about the processing time for storing the data in three tables.